# Replacing mixed string/date values within a pandas column with only the date component

Tags: python, pandas, replace

I have a pandas df column containing both string and date information. I'd like to replace this column with only the date information. I think I can use the df.replace() function along with the regex=True option, but I'm really not sure how to go about doing this. I've tried a few ways, but can't seem to figure out the logic. Any and all help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is an example of the values found in the column:

> DATE_COLUMN

> Foo 11-2008 Bar

> Hip 12-2008 Hop

> Some_text 01-2009 some_more_text

I'd like to only replace the above cells with only the MM-YYYY data.

I also have another df with a similar pattern (but if I can understand how to solve the above, I think I'll be able to figure out this one):

> DATE_COLUMN

> Foo 12-2007 to 11-2008 Bar

> Hip 01-2008 to 12-2008 Hop

> Some_text 02-2008 to 01-2009 some_more_text

In this case, I'd want to replace each cell with only the second MM-YYYY element.

Once again, any and all help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the built in format extraction of `to_datetime` on cleaned data using `str.extract`:

```
df['date'] = df['date'].str.extract(r'.*(\d\d-\d\d\d\d)')
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"], format="%m-%Y")
```

The `.*` in the regex will deal with the double dates by keeping the last occurrence only.

Comment: I didn't know about the str.extract method! Furthermore, I don't know why you were downvoted. I was able to modify your solution to work perfectly for me. Thank you very much!